# MongoDB Changing from localhost ip

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out how to run MongoDB, and am running into the follow error below:

How do I change my IP, do I change this in my mongod.conf? I'm running MongoDB on Virtualbox inside the virtual machine, running Ubuntu 14.04.

`2015-01-19T01:02:38.625-0700 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused`

`2015-01-19T01:02:38.625-0700 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed`

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using? Is the MongoDB service running? What does `service mongodb status` return? Are you trying to connect from outside the virtual machine (e.g. your host system)?

Comment: Running Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to run this inside my VM on my host system. `service mongod status` says `mongod stop/waiting`

Comment: `stop/waiting` means, that the MongoDB service is not running, try `sudo service mongod start`

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me in getting MongoDB running and I didn't have to mess with changing any IP to match my VM:

1) edited /etc/mongodb.conf changed `db-path=data/db`

2) created data/db with the following:

`sudo mkdir -p /data/db/`

`sudo chown id -u /data/db`

3) ran mongod got an error with the following: `Please make at least 3379MB available in /data/db/journal or use --smallfiles`

4) re-ran with `mongod --small files`

5) opened another SSH window and ran `mongo`

6) mongodb loads - golden